# How to send one signal notification from asp.net webapi to ionic app

Tags: push-notification, onesignal

I'm developing android and iOS application using cordova ionic and I include one signal notification as a feature in my app.

I register onesignal and test to push notification. It's work well.

Now I want to send onesignal notification from asp.net web api to perticular user.
I have tried [this](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/server-api-overview) url but I failed. Also i am unable to get device token in my app.

Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

You need to call [window.plugins.OneSignal.getIds](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ionic-sdk#section--getids-) and store  `ids.userId` from the callback.

You can then make a POST call to the https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications endpoint from your ASP.NET code setting the `include_player_ids` to the userId retrieved from your app.

There is an ASP.NET example towards the bottom of the endpoint documentation page listed below.
https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#create-notification